# Is it necessary to add my project to the environment variables PATH or PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, constructor

I been reading a lot on how to set up the projects and having the `__init__.py` in the folder structures and also one above in the root folder where the project is been sitting.

I have this folder structure, and running in pycharm work, since it adds the path to environment variables when it starts.

```
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\pak1
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\pak1\pak_num1.py
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\pak1\__init__.py

C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program\program.py
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program\__init__.py

C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\__init__.py
C:\test_folder\folder_struture\__init__.py
```

When I try to run `program.py`  where I have:

```
from project.pak1 import pak_num1
```

I get the error that the module doesn't exists.  when I add the project to the `PYTHONPATH` variable or the `PATH` variable in my windows machine, now everything works fine. Is it possible that the tutorials are missing the part of setting the root folder of the project into the environs since they assume you already did it?

For every project do I need to put the root project into the environment variables or is there is a way for python to recognize that is in a python module/python structure?

Adding it to the environ will let me `import` absolute,
but if I try to do  and relative  with

```
from ..pak1 import pak_num1
```

I get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If I run `program.py`  does it look for the `__init__.py` in the same folder and if it find it, does it go one level up to find another `__init__.py` and so on to get the structure?

Comment: How are you running the script? `program.py` is in `C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program`, which means `C:\test_folder\folder_struct` is probably *not* added to the list of directors where Python will look for packages.

Comment: You can manually add directories in various ways, but it's usually simpler to *install* your project into one of the known directories "hard-coded" into the Python interpreter itself, which is one reason to use virtual environments: instead of installing into system directories, you run an instance of Python that already knows about the virtual environment.

Comment: i cd to C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program     and then did 'python program.py'

Comment: That adds `C:\test_folder\folder_structure\project\program` to the search path, but not ``C:\test_folder\folder_structure\``, which is where Python needs to look to find the package `project`.

Comment: if i cd to the folder that has the script that i want to run,   example cd to "C:\test_folder\folder_struture\project\program" and write in the command line "python program.py" i get the issue with the module not found, but if i cd to  "C:\test_folder\folder_struture" and then do "python project/program/program.py" this way does work,  chepner i think this is the way python know whats the root/upper folder of the structure and add that to the search path.  so the trick is to cd or start the command line at the root folder

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing lots of little scripts and start wanting to organize some of them into utility packages, mostly to be used by other scripts (ouside those packages), put all the scripts that are to be called from the command-line (your entry-points for execution, or main scripts, or whatever name you want to call this scripts that run as commands from the command line) side-by-side, in the same folder as the root folders of all your packages.

Then you can import (anything) from any package from the top-level scripts. Starting the execution from the top level scripts not only gives access to any package, as also allows for all the package internal imports to work, given that an `__init__.py` file rests in all package/sub-package folder/sub-folder.

For code inside a package to import from another sibling package (sibling at the top-level folder) you need either to append to `sys.path` the sibling package, or for example, to wrap everything yet in another folder again with an `__init__.py` file there. Then again you should start execution from outside this overall package, not from the scripts that were top-level before you do this.

Think of packages as something to be imported for use, not to start running from a random inner entry point.

Many times a better alternative is to configure a `virtualenv`, and every package you install in the environment becomes known in that environment. This also isolates the dependencies from project to project, including the Python version at use if you need. Note that this is solving also a different problem, but a hairy one, by the way.